# Which version of Ubuntu for HP 250 G6 Celeron 4GB?

Tags: system-installation

I have purchased an HP 250 G6 Celeron 4GB notebook. Which version of Ubuntu can I load on it? This is a brand new laptop with Windows 10 Home edition running on it.

Regards
Ali

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is capable of running all versions of Ubuntu.

I would recommed the [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) standard version (min 25 GB disk drive, min 2GB RAM, min 2GHz CPU speed). You won't have too much problems but it's true that there are other Ubuntu flavours that will give you more free RAM for your own stuff (like Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu).

Whatever you choose, always choose a supported version, with security updates, 18.04 versions are going to have support for at least 5 years, so it's a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended Minimum System Requirements published in Ubuntu Documentation, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)